# add_filter function not working as expected

Tags: sql, wordpress, add-filter

I'm trying to edit a `wp_query` in WordPress using the [`add_filter` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter). When I `var_dump` my query `request` it outputs the SQL as expected.

However, when it runs it returns an error with a different query! Does anyone know why the query might change, and change so much!

Query from the `request` `var_dump` (as expected):

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.*, 
    ( 3959 * acos(
         cos( radians(52.486243) ) 
         * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
         * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-1.890401) ) 
         + sin( radians(52.486243) ) 
         * sin( radians( lat ) ) 
         ) ) 
     AS distance , lat AS  latitude , lng AS longitude 
FROM wp_posts  
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id) 
INNER JOIN lat_lng_post ON wp_posts.ID = lat_lng_post.post_id 
WHERE 1=1  
AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (2) ) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'event' 
AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) 
AND ( (wp_postmeta.meta_key LIKE 'date_%_start-date' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) <= '20140704')
AND  (mt1.meta_key LIKE 'date_%_end-date' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS SIGNED) >= '20140627') ) 
AND lat_lng_post.lat = lat 
AND lat_lng_post.lng = lng 
AND substr(wp_postmeta.meta_key, 1, 6) = substr(mt1.meta_key, 1, 6)  
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
HAVING distance <= 20 
ORDER BY distance ASC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

And this is the query that shows below the error `[Unknown column 'lat' in 'field list']` (not expected):

```
SELECT wp_posts.*, 
    ( 3959 * acos( 
        cos( radians(52.486243) ) 
        * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
        * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-1.890401) ) 
        + sin( radians(52.486243) ) 
        * sin( radians( lat ) ) 
     ) ) AS distance , lat AS latitude , lng AS longitude 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 1=1 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'acf-field' 
AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) 
AND wp_posts.post_name = 'field_535e6b9ffe3da' 
AND lat_lng_post.lat = lat 
AND lat_lng_post.lng = lng 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
HAVING distance <= 20 
ORDER BY distance ASC 
LIMIT 0, 1
```

NOTE

I have a custom table called `lat_lng_post` which has three columns, `post_id`, `lat`, `lng` to store location data for each event (custom post type).

EDIT all add_filter functions being used on the query:

```
function distance_query($distance) {

    $lat = $_SESSION['search']['lat'];
    $lng = $_SESSION['search']['long'];


    $distance .= ", 
    ( 3959 * acos(
         cos( radians(".$lat.") ) 
         * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
         * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(".$lng.") ) 
         + sin( radians(".$lat.") ) 
         * sin( radians( lat ) ) 
         ) ) 
     AS distance , lat AS  latitude , lng AS longitude";
    return $distance;
}
add_filter('posts_fields', 'distance_query');



// add lat_lng_post table inner join
function lat_lng_join($join) {
    $join = str_replace('(wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id)', '(wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id) INNER JOIN lat_lng_post ON wp_posts.ID = lat_lng_post.post_id', $join);
    return $join;
}
add_filter('posts_join', 'lat_lng_join');


// set lat lng definition
function lat_lng_define($define) {
    $define .= ' AND lat_lng_post.lat = lat AND lat_lng_post.lng = lng';
    return $define;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'lat_lng_define');


// HAVING distance less than user distance
function having_distance($having) {
    $radius = $_SESSION['search']['distance'];
    $having = 'wp_posts.ID HAVING distance <= '.$radius.'';
    return $having;
}
add_filter('posts_groupby', 'having_distance');

// if sorting by distance
function sort_distance($sortdistance) {
    $sortdistance = 'distance ASC';
    return $sortdistance;
}
if( $_SESSION['search']['sort-by'] == 'distance' ) :
    add_filter('posts_orderby', 'sort_distance');
endif;


function add_additional_where_condition($where) {
    $where .= " AND substr(wp_postmeta.meta_key, 1, 6) = substr(mt1.meta_key, 1, 6) ";
    return $where;
}

// fix for setting the date to search field
function date_to( $to ) {
    $to = str_replace("mt1.meta_key = 'date_%_end-date'", "mt1.meta_key LIKE 'date_%_end-date'", $to);
    return $to;
}

// fix for setting the date from search field   
function date_from( $from ) {
    $from = str_replace("meta_key = 'date_%_start-date'", "meta_key LIKE 'date_%_start-date'", $from);
    return $from;
}

// fix for ordering by date
function order_date( $like ) {
    $like = str_replace("mt2.meta_key = 'date_%_end-date'", "mt2.meta_key LIKE 'date_%_end-date'", $like);
    return $like;
}

// fix for searching by LIKE post title, requires all characters to match 
function title_filter( $where, &$wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( $search_term = $wp_query->get( 'title_like' ) ) {
        $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE \'%' . esc_sql( like_escape( $search_term ) ) . '%\'';
    }
    return $where;
}
```

Also, this is the `wp_query` itself that these functions are being added to:

```
// add query for title
    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'title_filter', 10, 2 );

// dates to and from logic
    add_filter('posts_where', 'date_from');
    add_filter('posts_where', 'date_to');
    add_filter('posts_where', 'order_date');
    add_filter('posts_where', 'add_additional_where_condition');


// get date inputs from search
    $date1 = str_replace('/', '-', $_SESSION['search']['from']);
    $when = date("Ymd", strtotime($date1));

    $date2 = str_replace('/', '-', $_SESSION['search']['to']);
    $when2 = date("Ymd", strtotime($date2));

    $year = date('Y');




// Declare the query arguments 
    if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { 
        $paged = get_query_var('paged'); 
    } else if ( get_query_var('page') ) {
        $paged = get_query_var('page'); 
    } else {
        $paged = 1; 
    }

// make keywords an array
    $keywordString = $_SESSION['search']['keyword'];
    $keywords = explode(', ', $keywordString);

    $taxQuery = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array (
            'taxonomy' => 'main-cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $_SESSION['search']['cat']
        )
    );

    if( $_SESSION['search']['keyword'] != '' ) {
        $taxQuery[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'sub-cat',
            'field' => 'name',
            'terms' => $keywords
        );
    }

    $args = array(
        // general
        'post_type' => 'event',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'cache_results' => false,
        'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
        'update_post_term_cache' => false,

        'meta_key' => $_SESSION['search']['sort-key'],
        'orderby' => $_SESSION['search']['sort-by'],
        'order' => 'ASC',

        // category filter
        'tax_query' => $taxQuery,

        // date filter

        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'date_%_start-date',
                'value' => $when2,
                'compare' => '<=',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC'
            ),
            array (
                'key' => 'date_%_end-date',
                'value' => $when,
                'compare' => '>=',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC'
            )

        )
    );


    $temp = $wp_query;
    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: I guess you're trying to modify the SQL of more than a single query. Can you share the filter code? Is it a main query or a secondary query, you're trying to modify?

Comment: Hi, it's the only query running on a page, it's essentially a search page, with the permalink `/event-search/`, will edit my question with all of the `add_filter` functions.

Comment: The filters affect all your `WP_Query` queries, except the `get_posts()` wrappers, where the filters are suppressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to setup up `posts_*` filters for a *secondary query*, but you **forget** to remove the filters afterwards, so they are affecting other queries that run later.

**i)** You can remove a filter with the [`remove_filter()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter) function. Here's an example :

```
// Add some filter:
add_filter( 'some_filter', 'some_filter_callback', $priority );

// Run a secondary query:
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Remove the previous filter:
remove_filter( 'some_filter', 'some_filter_callback', $priority );
```

where the filter *priority* must match.

**ii)** Another way would be to use add the `remove_filter()` inside the `some_filter_callback()` function. For example:

```
add_filter( 'some_filter', 'some_filter_callback' );
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

where

```
some_filter_callback( $string )
{
    // Remove the current filter:
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    // Some modifications to the input:
    // ...

    // Output:
    return $string;
}
```

This will make sure your filter will only run once.

**iii)** If you're trying to modify the main query, you can restrict the filter with:

```
if( ! is_admin() && is_main_query() )
{
     // ...
}
```

or

```
if( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() )
{
     // ...
}
```

if you're using the `pre_get_posts` hook, where `$query` is the input argument.

**iv)** Another option would be to create a new class that extends the `WP_Query` and contains all the filters you want:

```
class My_Search_Query extends WP_Query
{
   // ...
}
```

where you use

```
$query = new My_Search_Query( $args );
```

to run the query.

Comment: Great! This got rid of the SQL error, weirdly it's broken the pagination for the page though, strange!

Comment: That's great. Is the paging not changing in the SQL query?

Comment: Ah, sorted it by changing the front page to a static page in the settings :)